# what's the point to use non-null assertion?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to typescript and my textbook says:

**A non-null assertion should be used only when you know that a null value cannot occur. A runtime error will be caused if you apply the assertion and a null value does occur.**

so I write a simple typescript file to verify(with "strictNullChecks": true):

```
function calculateTax(amount: number, format: boolean): string | number | null {
    if (amount === 0) {
        return null;
    }
    const calcAmount = amount * 1.2;
    return format ? `$${calcAmount.toFixed(2)}` : calcAmount;
}
let taxValue: string | number = calculateTax(0, false)!;
```

Below is my questions:

Q1- we can see that `calculateTax(0, false)` will return null, after I ran the program, there is no run time error at all? why the author says there will be run time error?

Q2-I can just rewrite the statement without non-null assertion as:

```
let taxValue: string | number = calculateTax(0, false);
```

it has no compilation error and run time error, works perfectly, so what's the point to use non-null assertion?

Comment: There will be a runtime error *if you do something with the `null`*. TS compiles to JS, so naturally you can have `null`s and the mere presence of one doesn't cause a problem. But `calculateTax(0, false).toString()` would result in a TypeError.

Comment: As for Q2 - you could but that can still return `null`, so it's not just `string` or `number`.

Comment: @VLAZ   I understand that  `calculateTax(0, false).toString()` would result in a TypeError. So we just need to use typeof to tell, that's exactly my question, what's the point to use non-null assertion if you still need to manually check it?

Comment: Non-null assertions are for when you *as a programmer* know that you won't get a `null` but TS cannot figure it out. E.g., you do `calculateTax(userInput, false)` which *could* result with `null` for `userInput = 0` but you are actually filtering that value before it gets to that point of the code. TS cannot figure this out (e.g., it doesn't know of your validation logic) but it does know that the result *could* be `null`. You, however, know that you won't have `userInput = 0` ever, so you can just tell that to TS.

Answer (score 13):

I guess you misunderstood what a type assertion does. It's not something that compiler ensures, it's a kind of "waiver" you give the compiler saying "I hereby renounce the right to have this type checked, I guarantee that it will be X at run-time and I'm responsible for  consequences if it is not".

By using the `!` assertion you're basically telling the compiler "shut up, I know better, this never gonna be null". The compiler has no option but to agree with you, but if you don't keep your promise (which you don't), a run time fault is imminent.

Obviously, a type assertion is almost never a good idea. Finally, the whole point of Typescript is to have your types statically checked. Think twice before putting `!` or `as` here and there.

Comment: What if we are in a situation where we have, e.g., checked before that the value indeed is not null? Then ! seems straightforward and exactly the reason to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you run compilation with `--strictNullChecks`, a compilation error

```
error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

should be raised. I guess the author intended to state that non-null assertions lead to runtime exception if you continue to use the object that supposedly is non-null.

For example calling a function on `taxValue` in your example above with the non-null assertion would not warn you that the value might be null but if it is null and you call the function during runtime it will raise an exception.

The non-null assertion can be used for you to remove falsy warning that a knonw-non-null variable whose type could be null can be used as if it were not nullable.