# How to fix the forbidden non-null assertion in TypeScript and React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have code like below:

```
type ItemProps = {
    status?: string;
}

<Items status={status!} /> // error here: warning  Forbidden non-null assertion
                           //                   @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-
```

assertion

I am getting a forbidden non-null assertion error.

How can I fix this error?

I have tried

```
<Items status={status && status}/>
```

but this doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why do you want to use the "non-null assertion operator"?

The `status` property can either be `string | undefined`.
What about passing an empty string or perhaps assigning a default value when you don't want to specify a value for `status`?

```
<Items status={status || ''}/>
```

Or:

```
type ItemProps = {
  status?: string;
};

const Items: React.FC<ItemProps> = ({ status = 'statusDefaultValue' }) => <div>Some JSX</div>
```

It's a bit hard for me to understand your case without knowing the context. Hope this can help.

Comment: it could be null so using non-nullish operator

Comment: Not sure I'm following. By using `!` operator you're telling the compiler that `status` is never going to be `null`.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951909/whats-the-point-to-use-non-null-assertion

Comment: Sure, there are cases when you're sure a specific value exists because you've checked it before, or perhaps you can use a type guard to check for a property in an object.
As per OP's question, I suggested that non-nullish operator was not the way to go in order to achieve their expected result.
If you have an answer I'd love to read it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove optional modifier in two ways.

1-st by [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) utility type:

```
interface Foo{
  a?: string;
  b?: number;
}

type Foo2 = Required<Foo>
```

2-nd by [Mapping Modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers):

```
// Removes 'optional' attributes from a type's properties
type Bar = {
  [P in keyof Foo]-?: number;
}
```

Also you might want to constructs a type by excluding `null` and `undefined` from Type by [NonNullable utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype):

```
type NonNullable<T> = Exclude<T, null | undefined>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the nullish coalescing operator (`??`) instead of a logical or (`||`), as it is a safer operator as some might prefer, like the following:

```js
<Items status={status ?? ''}/>
```